CI/CD error for deployment of ConversationMessageDefinition
We have CI/CD error failures when we try to validate or deploy ConversationMessageDefinition
src/conversationMessageDefinitions/ComForum.conversationMessageDefinition-meta.xml: Could not infer a metadata type

Try this:

A metadata type lookup for "ComForum.conversationMessageDefinition-meta.xml" found the following close matches:
-- Did you mean ".ConversationChannelDefinition-meta.xml" instead for the "ConversationChannelDefinition" metadata type?

Additional suggestions:
Confirm the file name, extension, and directory names are correct. Validate against the registry at:
<https://github.com/forcedotcom/source-deploy-retrieve/blob/main/src/registry/metadataRegistry.json>

If the type is not listed in the registry, check that it has Metadata API support via the Metadata Coverage Report:
<https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage>

If the type is available via Metadata API but not in the registry

- Open an issue <https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues>
- Add the type via PR. Instructions: <https://github.com/forcedotcom/source-deploy-retrieve/blob/main/contributing/metadata.md>

The same error is occurred on some of the local environment while on some other it doesn't occur.
What might be the issue and what is the solution or workaround for this?

Looks like the problem was in the old version of SF CLI on both CI/CD server and affected local environment.
Error has been gone after updating locally sfdx cli using
sf update command on affected local environment and using command
sh "sudo npm update --global @salesforce/cli" in Jenkins.
